# Inserir licença como dependência em um projeto Maven

Tags: maven, netbeans, injeção-de-dependência, dependências

**EDIT:** o problema ainda persiste, postei abaixo, em minha resposta, novas informações acerca do problema.
Obrigado.

Olá! Eu fiz alguns testes usando a biblioteca JxBrowser e tenho a intenção de utilizá-la no meu projeto acadêmico.

No entanto, meu projeto é no Maven, que estou desenvolvendo usando o Netbeans, e mesmo eu colocando o repositório do Jxbrowser e suas dependências no arquivo POM.xml, ele não consegue reconhecer meu arquivo de licenca.jar

Inseri manualmente meu arquivo como uma dependência mas mesmo assim ao executar ele acusa de não estar licenciado, aparentemente os arquivos baixados pelo repositório não consegue achar a minha licença; alguém já passou por algum problema parecido que possa me ajudar?
Desde já agradeço.

Abaixo está uma imagem mostrando como estão as dependências no Netbeans.

[image: dependencia do netbeans]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Descobri que não estava referenciando o arquivo jar correto, mas sim o que estava no repositório com.teamdev.jxbrowser (versão trial padrão), e não o que arquivo que está em minha máquina, neste caso, após os 30 dias, ele expirou.
Então, o problema ainda persiste, na imagem retrato as mensagens que o netbeans exibe na compilação e execução do projeto, e as partes do pom.xml relevantes ao arquivo .jar que quero inserir.
Obs: já instalei manualmente pelo netbeans e ele ainda assim não encontra o jar.

```
<repository>
   <id>mylibid</id>
   <url>file:${basedir}</url>
</repository>
<dependency>
  <groupId>mylibid</groupId>
  <artifactId>licence</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <type>jar</type>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Consegui resolver meu problema!
Inseri novamente uma nova dependência, e manualmente o arquivo licenca.jar; no entanto, desta vez coloquei o ID de grupo (groupID) desta dependência o mesmo da do Jxbrowser no arquivo POM.xml (com.teamdev.jxbrowser) e automaticamente ela ficou associada à biblioteca.
Espero que alguém que tenha um problema similar possa resolver também.